# Expression of type 'System.Int16' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-5, lambda

```
public IQueryable<Users> SelectAdmin<TProp>(string sSortExpression, string sSortOrder ,long[] IAds, int iStart, int iEnd, long iId)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Users));
        var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Users, TProp>>(Expression.Property(param, sSortExpression), param);
        if (sSortOrder == "asc")
        {

            return objCouponUow.Repository<Users>().Entities.Where(x => x.UserGroup == 9 && x.Validate == 0 && x.Deleted == false && IAds.Contains(x.UserParent)).OrderBy(propExpression).Skip(iStart).Take(iEnd - iStart);
        }

    }
```

this is my function .. i Am getting the  error  in line :

```
  var propExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Users, TProp>>(Expression.Property(param, sSortExpression), param);
```

When the 'sSortExpression' which is a column in Users Table is of Type Varchar , No Problem  But If its Int type..  Error Occurs 
Expression of type 'System.Int16' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

How can i Correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `<Tprop>` is not of the Type `Int16` and the string you are passing which is a columnname of the type `Int16`

You can simply specify the `<Tprop>` wherever you are calling the function `SelectAdmin<TProp>`.

for example:

```
`SelectAdmin<int>(.......your parameters here);`
```

if the sSortExpression is of the Type int16. 
 If it is of the type `DateTime` you can  call like this

```
 SelectAdmin<DateTime>(.......your parameters here);
```

Answer (score 1):

By a chance you dont assign there an object(sSortExpression), cause you said it is a column, maybe u assigned item object collection as int, so got error.

Comment: @wolks  sSortExpression is a string which is a column name. if the column is of type string.. Works perfectly. But when it is of type Int. Error occurs. What could be the solution ?

Comment: @NoMan but users is an object, right? Maybe it is somewhat connected... at objCouponUow, look through it, and check if there isnt errors.